# K8s PVC is pending state always

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

This is my StorageClass, Pv and PVC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sUfM.jpg)

This is my PVC Describe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP6vo.jpg)

Comment: It's best to copy and paste text into your question rather than linking to an image. That makes the question searchable and thus potentially valuable to others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It was successful!
if you want it to be in `Bound` state as soon as the volume is created, switch
`volumeBindingMode: WatiForFirstCustomer` to `volumeBindingMode: Immediate` in your sohialsc.yml file.

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Link references:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/